# Forcing `open` command to open unsigned app?

Tags: macos, terminal, security, code-signing

I've got my Security preferences set to allow apps downloaded from "Mac App Store and identified developers."  When I try to open an unsigned app:

```
open xyz.app
```

I see the following:

[image: App can't be opened]

Usually, I right-click on the app and click "Open".  This brings up a similar dialogue, but this one includes an "open anyway"-type button:

[image: App can't be opened, with open button]

Is there a way to do this only using the `open` command -- something like:

```
open --even-if-unsigned xyz.app
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

1. Create and add a Gatekeeper label to the app. (‘Approved’ is an arbitrary string.)

   ```
   spctl --add --label "Approved" /path/to/xyz.app
   ```
2. Approve all apps with the label.

   ```
   spctl --enable --label "Approved"
   ```

   This only needs to be done once and adding the same named label to apps in the future automatically enables their access.
3. Open the app as usual.

   ```
   open xyz.app
   ```

For more information about spctl (SecAssessment system policy security), see the man page.

Comment: Ah, a new addition to the list of things that I formerly only knew how to do GUI-ly, and now can do on the command line!  Thanks!

Answer (score 34):

You could strip the quarantine from the app:

```
xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine /path/to/xyz.app
```

You may want/need to use `sudo` for that command, depending on permissions.

Then Gatekeeper isn't involved, at all. Of course, that also means that the signature isn't verified, which removes an important safety feature.

Comment: I love this answer, too.  It's a pity I can only pick one!

Comment: This worked for my manual installed OpenJDK installation. Thanks!

Comment: On Catalina, this is the only answer that worked for me.

Comment: On Big Sur, this is the only one that worked for me as well.